# Should I use FMA explicitly in C++AMP for GPU kernels?

Tags: c++-amp, fma

For example,
I have an expression like `a = b * c + d * e + f * g + h * i + j`. Should I instead write `a = fma(a, c, fma(d, e, fma(f, g, fma(h, i, j))))`?

Will compiler automatically optimize the expression? Or is the fma form actually better than the plain form?

I found it hard to know what a kernel is compiled to in C++AMP... Should I just switch to OpenCL?